# Wordpress: Adding meta values like title and description for Pages from custom database

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a plugin that creates plugin specific database table rows that then are turned into pages. I have got this work with URL redirect and have been able to lay out the page. Now I am having some problems.

Problems:

1. Creating header title for the page. It currently shows page not found.
2. Creating description for meta SEO. Meta description is currently blank.
3. Showing these custom created pages to be added in WP menu.

I know these are not pages, and I have lost most of the wp functionality by doing this and not using custom post types but one of the main requirements of the clients was that the database have separate tables for their data.

I need some help or reference regarding these problems. Links for examples and articles would do or any free plugins that actually do this.

I'd really appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: One thing I did was create a separate header template for my custom pages. Now I gotto find a way to pass variables into it.

Comment: @segarci its a whole plugin with a lot of codes, I'm almost having to create a custom solution outside wp for this and only lay it out on wordpress admin.
I still have to use wp menu for it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned your self, using your current technique you will not able to take advantage of WordPress in real sense. You may use custom posts and then use wp cron to copy get the data from there to your own table.

Comment: But that would copy the data to the post_meta table. My client does not want that to happen.